# how to understand 'test' in the makefile's scripts?

Tags: c++, makefile

```
@if test  ! –d /c/objs;\
Then \
  Mkdirs /c/objs;\
fi
```

as titled, what's the meaning for the 'test' after@if in makefile, is there one detailed web page description the scripts in makefile?

Comment: The answer is that `make` invokes a POSIX shell (`sh`) to run the recipes.  You can read about this by Googling phrases such as "introduction to sh", etc.  As Sebastian notes below, though, `test` is a separate program that the shell runs.  An aside: please be careful when copying or typing example code into questions.  Languages are mostly case-sensitive and so `Then` is a completely different operator than `then`, and the former is not recognized by the shell.  Ditto, most likely, for `Mkdirs` vs. `mkdir`

Answer (score 8):

`test` (manpage [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test)) is a UNIX utility for testing conditions, e.g. file types. Therefore, this is not a command provided by `make` or the m4 language, but an external command that gets called.